# Need more clarification of SEQUENCE TRANSFORMATION challenge of Codeeval

Tags: python, algorithm

[**CHALLENGE DESCRIPTION:**](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/130/)

> There are two sequences. The first sequence consists of digits "0" and
>   "1", the second one consists of letters "A" and "B". The challenge is
>   to determine whether it's possible to transform a given binary
>   sequence into a string sequence using the following rules: 
>   1. "0" can be transformed into non empty sequence of letters "A" ("A", "AA", "AAA" etc.) 
>   2. "1" can be transformed into non empty sequence of letters "A" ("A", "AA", "AAA" etc.) or to non empty sequence of letters "B" ("B", "BB",
>   "BBB" etc).
>
> For each test case print out "Yes" if the transformation is possible,
>   otherwise print "No". E.g.

**INPUT SAMPLE:**

```
 1010 AAAAABBBBAAAA 
 00 AAAAAA
 01001110 AAAABAAABBBBBBAAAAAAA
 1100110 BBAABABBA
```

**OUTPUT SAMPLE:**

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
No
```

**MY UNDERSTANDING OF THE QUESTION**

> As I understand the question states two rules,
>
> **RULE 1:** A^n <-(0)
>   **RULE 2:** (A/B)^n <-(1)
>
> Using this logic if I solve the given examples I would get Yes and No
>   respectively which satisfies the examples.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> 1. 1010 AAAAABBBBAAAA - YES
> 2. None<-(1)  AAAAA<-(0) BBBB<-(1) AAAA<-(0)
> 3. This is yes because this does not break either rule.
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> 1. 1100110 BBAABABBA - NO
> 2. None<-(1) BB<-(1) AA<-(0) B<-(0) A<-(1) BB<-(1) A<-(0)
> 3. This is No because B<-(0) is not true as per rule 1

But when I am implementing this logic in my code, the results are not accepted. What is wrong with my logic/understanding of the questions?

**My CODE**

```
import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
  digits, word = test.split()
  seq = None
  result = None
  count  = 0
  word = word[::-1]
  digits = digits[::-1]
  for character in word:
    #print character, seq, count, digits, digits[count]
    if not seq:
      seq = character
      continue
    if seq != character:
        if seq == 'B' and digits[count] == '0':
          result = "No"
          break
        seq = character
        count+=1
  if result:
    print result
  else:
    print "Yes"

test_cases.close()
```

**REALTIME TEST CASES AND RESULTS** (*through my code*)

```
0000 AAA
Yes
111111000111001110001110101100100 AABBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAABBBAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
No
1101110110011101000010101110110101000100011110001101010001 BBBBAABAABBAAAAAABABBBBBBAAAAAAAABAABAABBBABBAAABBBBBBBABBBBAAAAABBBABBBAABBA
No
0100011111110101101000100010011101010111110111101011000110111111100101011011101010111100101000010011110 AABAAAAAABAABBBBABAABAAAAABBBAABAAAAABABAABABBBBBAABBBAAABABBABAAABBABBABAABAABABBBBBAAAABAABABAAAABBBAAABA
No
000001010111001000110010000111101111000100000110011000010011000010110010101111110110111101111100101 BBABBBAAABABBAAABBABBBBAABBBBAAAAABAABBAABABBABABABBAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAABAAABABAABAAAAABBABBBABBBA
No
1 B
Yes
00010000100010000111011110110001111001110110101000100010111110010 BBBABABABBABBAAABBBBABBBABBABABABBBAAABBAAABBBBABABBAABBBAAAABBBB
No
10 BBBBBAAAAAAA
Yes
10100000010110110100001011000011100000100010100001110 BBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAABBBAAABBBBBBAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAA
No
1111111000100100000110011110 AAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBABAAA
No
000000101 AABBBABABAAAABABBBB
No
1000110111100110100000110111010100101011111100110001111000101100001 BBAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB
No
00111011000111010101100001 AAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB
No
010000101110000010110011001000110010000110111110101100100000011101011100100110001000000111100010010100011011100 ABBABAAABAABBAAAABBBAABAABABABBAAABBBAABBBABBAAAABAABABBBABABBAABABABBAABBABBBABBBBABBBABBBAABABBABAAABAAAAAABBBABA
No
000011 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBB
Yes
00110 AAAABBAA
Yes
1110011111001001110011001011100000110110001101000000100110101010000001101100010100001111011110110000100111000001100101001101100110011 BAABBBABABABBABAABBBBBBAABABAAAAAABBABBBBAAAAABABABABABAABABBAAAABBAABBAAABBBAAABABBBBBABBBABBAAABBABAAABBBBAAAABAAAAABBAABABABBBBBBABBBBBABABABABABBBAAAAAABABBBAAABBBBAABABABAABBBBBABAABBAABABBBAAABABBBBBBABA
No
01001111101000000001001110001100100011100011000010100011110111101111011010110101100001011001111101011100100011101010100011111 AAABAAAAAAABBBAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAABBBBBBAAAAAABBBAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAABBBAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBA
No
11001000011111000111001001110011000001100101 BBBBBBAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAABBBBBBAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB
No
1011100100010011110000111111111100101001010000011000011111001010111001011101010100000000 ABABAABABABABBAABABBBABABBBBABBAAABBBBABAAABABABBBABAAABAABBBAABAAAABBAAABBBBAAABAABABAABAAABBBBBABBBAA
No
10101100101000110 AABBBAAAABBAAAABABBBAABAABABAAAAAAABAABABAABBBBAAAAA
No
11010101101010010011000011100110011110101000001111010000000101010011001011111001000010101010110000000110100101100100110101000 AAAAAABBBBAAAAABBAAABBBAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAABBBAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
No
01 BBBBBAAAAAAA
Yes
1 BBBBBBAAAAAA
Yes
010111001100101011001101010010011111000101011111111000100000010010011101010011010011101101000000000000010111111010100110110101000101 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAABBAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAABBBAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAABBBBAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAABBAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAABBBBAAAAAABBBBAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAABBAAAAAABBBBAAAAAABAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAABBBBBAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAA
No
0111011101011001110011000011110100100 ABBABBABABBABABABAABBBAAABAABBAAAAABAAABAAABABBBABABBBAAABAB
No
110101010100100111101010111011100011010001010110011111000011001011101110100011001111100001111111 BAAABABAAABBBBAAABAABBBABBBAABBBBAAAABABAAABAAAAABBAAAAABBBBBAAABABAAABBABABAABABAABAABBBBAAABBABBABB
No
11101111000011101110101001100110111011110101011100000010001100011110100111111100110010111011100001101011101110110100100 ABAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAABBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAABBBBBBAABBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAABBBAAAABBBAAAAAABBBAAAAABBAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAA
No
0111100001110101011101001110001101101010011100110100001011011010011101001000110000111110110100001010011001101110001 BAAABBAABBBBABBBBABABABBABABABAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAABBABAAAABBAAABBBAABAAABABAAAABBABBABABBABAABBAABBBABBAAAAAAAABABBBBBAB
No
001010111001000001000101111100001100111011010100000010010010100101011011010110010110000 ABBAABBAAAAAAABABBAABBBABBAAABBABABABBAABABABAABAABAAABBAAABAABBAAAABBABBABBBAAAAAABABBBBAAABAABABAAABAABAAAAABBBBBABBBABBAABAABBBABBBBABAAABABBAAABBABA
No
001001001010100001101011111000001000100100000000011001001111001010001101 AAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAABAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB
No
00010010101110000100101 BBBAAAAABABABBAAAAABBBA
No
001011010111001010100011101011100000000000110110110101110001110110110010010100 AAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAABBBBBBABBBBBBAAAAABAAAABBAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAABBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
No
00010101011100100000 AAAAAAABABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
No
0001001000000011 BAAABBBBBABABAAAABBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAABBBAABAABABABBB
No
00100010101001011111101011010110010111001100010000001001011101101001110000001100110010101101111000111101010001101 BABBBBABAAABAAAABABBABBBAAAAABBAAABBBBAABABBBAAAAAABABBABABBBBBAABBBBBBAAAABABABABAAABAAAABABAABAABAABBABBBAAABABAAAAAAABAAABAAAAABAAABBBBBBBBAABABABBBAABAAAAAAAABABBAABBBABBBABBABBBB
No
01010011101101010010000000110101010000100011010000011101100111010101101100111001100 AABBAAABABABBBBBBBBBBAABBBBABAAABABAAABABAABABAAAAABABBABABABBBAABBAABBBBAABBBAAAAAABBAABBABAABBBBBAAAAABBBAAAABABBBAA
No
0 A
Yes
101001010101 BBBBAABAABAABBAAAABAABABBAABABBBBABABBAABABABAABBBBBBBAABAABBAABAABBAAAABABABAABABABABBABAAABBBABA
No
000011111010110010100000011101001110110101001111110101001110110101100000100001100011011010011000001010101111101010010100011010111011011001 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAABBBBBAAAAAAAABBAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAABAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAABBBBAAABAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAABAAAAAAAAABBBBBB
No
1110010000010010001100101010011010101 BBBABBBAAAABAAAABBBAAAAABAAAAABABAAAA
No
00100101101111100001000110110111010100110111100001101101011101100100001100111 ABBAABABABABAABBAABBBBBAABABBABBAABBBBAAAABAAABBABBBABAABBBBBBABAAAABBAABAAAABBAA
No
001110010101100010111010111000001010100101011110000011110101011110100011011100010111011110 AAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAABAABBBAAAAABBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAABABBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAABAABBAAAABBBBBAAAABBBBBABBBBBBBAABBBAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAABBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAAA
No
0000 AAAA
Yes
1100100011011000110101110110011100001101110000101111101110111011100010101010110100000110100110110010000101001101110110110101111010101100110 BBBAABBBABAABBABBAABBBAAAAAAAABBBABABBABABBBBAABBBBBAABAABBABAAABBABBABABBBABBABBBABAABBAABABAAAABABBABBBABAABAAABBABABAAAAABBBAAABABBABBAABBBAABABABBAAABAABAABBAAAAABBAABBAAABBABBBAABAABAB
No
000001000101110010110000100111100111001110110101110100001000001011111001001010010001111110000100011011010000110011010011010110 AABBAABBABBAAABAAABABAAAABBABAAABBAAABBAABBABAABABAABBBBBAABBAAABBAABAAABABABABAABAABAABABAAAABBBAAABBBBBBAAABAAAABABBAABBABBA
No
1011000100010001010010111100100011100101000001010010010011001100100011000001111000011000001100011001101000110010010010101011100010001110010 ABABBABAAABAABBAABBBBBABABBBBBBAABAAAAAAABBBAABBABAAAAAAAAABABAABABBAAAAAAABABBAAAABBBBBBBBBABBABBBABAABAABAABBBABBAABBBBAAAABAABBBBBBBBAAB
No
110011011010101110010010100110010010110011111000100011011101110000110111 AABABABBABBAABBABBABAAAABBBAABBBBBBBABABBBBBABABABBBAAABABBABABBABAABBBBABABB
No
01001 ABBBAB
No
00010110110 BABABBAABAABABBBABABABBABBABB
No
```

Comment: how was the answer then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1` matches **one** or more elements, either `A` or `B`.

Your understanding is incorrect here, as you appear to think matching 0 times is valid too:

> 1. 1010 AAAAABBBBAAAA - YES
> 2. None<-(1) AAAAA<-(0) BBBB<-(1) AAAA<-(0)

Here the `1` matches *at least **one*** `A` character, the `0` then matches the remaining `A` characters, then the next `1` matches the `B` sequence of characters, etc.:

- A<-(1) AAAA<-(0) BBBB<-(1) AAAA<-(0)

As a result, your very first sample is already wrong:

```
0000 AAA
```

This must match **at least** 4 characters, 3 `A` characters would not match this as each `0` must match at least one `A` each. The answer here must therefore be "No".